# Is there a way to force a user to use the up and down arrow keys in an <input type="number">?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have the following input box:

[image]

The input box's HTML code is as follows:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="50" defaultValue="12"/>
```

**Therefore, my questions are, please:**

Is there a way to force the user to use the up and down arrow keys and disallow the user from deleting/modifying the number in the input box directly? If so, how can I do this either in HTML or using React.js?

Comment: UX concerns aside, not all browsers fully support the `number` input type, so I would strongly recommend either not doing this or building your own custom control instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the user to the `ArrowUp` and `ArrowDown` keys on [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) by checking the [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property:

```
document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (!['ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown'].includes(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect keypresses happening in the input box and reject them.   The onkeypress event doesn't get triggered by an up or down arrow press in a number input box (at least in chrome).

```
document.querySelector('#num').onkeypress = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this though - there's no guarantee that the user will have a browser the supports the input spinner.

You should instead observe any changes to the input and make sure that the change is triggered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onKeyPress=this.your_key_eventlister_function()` in your input field
then in your function
            
            `your_key_eventlistener_function(e){
                 if(e.key != 'ArrowUp' || e.key !='ArrowDown'){
                    e.preventDefault();
                  }
              }`